# How to generate RSS feeds and provide to the users

Tags: php, rss

i am currently developing a website where i need to generate RSS feeds and provide to the users to get frequent updates.

Please guide me on how to do this...

Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Gourav

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/xml/rss/custom_feeds/) too...

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170803185856/http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/xml/rss/custom_feeds/index.html

Answer (score 3):

[Creating a custom rss feed with php.](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/xml/rss/custom_feeds/)

You definetly need to do some google searches before you start to post questions like this ( there may be millions of ways to aproach this ) .

Comment: Dang you beat my answer... 50 sec.

Comment: @ClemDesm: it's a war with these kind of questions :)

Comment: @poelinca : you mean simple googled question, the OP didn't even try before asking here ? :)

Comment: I am really sorry... i tried searching in google.... i could not identify the one which would suit me as i am very new to this web development... I am sorry.

Comment: @ClemDesm: exactly what i mean .

Comment: @gourav: no biggie , however the first rule you need to learn ( and master for that purpose ) for any kind of development is how to search and where .

Answer (score 2):

An RSS feed is basically just an XML document which you serve on the internet, just like a regular web page. A typical approach is to read your data from a database, convert it into a raw XML format, and then apply an XSLT to convert it to RSS. You don't have to use a database though, hand-edited XML files would, theoretically speaking, work as well.

The wikipedia article on RSS ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS ) should get you started on the file format and how to embed it into your web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Yahoo's BOSS API](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2008/07/16/yahoo-boss-api/), i used it for my iPhone app of similar nature to what you want to do. Its free and they dont limit your IP requests :)